# List to csv Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

When I try to save a Python list in a csv, the csv have the items that I want to save separated by each character.

I have a list like this with links:

```
links = ['https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/MLC-2150551226-departamento-los-talaveras-id-117671-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=01bab66e-7cd3-43ce-b3d7-8389260b443d', 
         'https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/MLC-2148268902-departamento-los-espinos-id-116373-_JM#position=2&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=01bab66e-7cd3-43ce-b3d7-8389260b443d']
```

Im trying to save this to a csv with this code:

```
with open('links.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(links)
```

The result I get from the list is the link in a row but each character in a column.

- How can I get the links separated by rows but in the same column?

Comment: What do you expect the resulting csv file to be in this case?  `links` is supposed to be a list of *rows*; if you are passing a string for each row, `writerows` will consider each string to be a list of characters.

Comment: rather than using a `csv.writer()` you can try `f.writelines()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`writer.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) expects the parameter to be an iterable of row lists (quoting the docs: "A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects"); right now it's interpreting your link strings as rows of 1-character columns (since a string is indeed an iterable of strings).

In short, you'll need to wrap each link in a list (an 1-tuple would do too), e.g. with a generator:

```
writer.writerows([link] for link in links)
```

Comment: I thought about this. Do you think what I'm doing is ok or rather must solve the problem in other way?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('links.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   for link in links:
      writer.writerow([link])
```

This should help you

Answer (score 1):

Writing a single string to a CSV row is kind of dicey with a `csv.writer()` as it is expecting a "list of lists" as input and a "list of strings" looks a lot like a "list of lists".

Since we are not really taking and advantage of the capabilities of the `csv` package, we might just directly use the file handle to do our writing.

```py
links = [
    'https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/MLC-2150551226-departamento-los-talaveras-id-117671-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=01bab66e-7cd3-43ce-b3d7-8389260b443d', 
    'https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/MLC-2148268902-departamento-los-espinos-id-116373-_JM#position=2&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=01bab66e-7cd3-43ce-b3d7-8389260b443d'
]

with open('links.csv', 'w') as f:
    for link in links:
        f.write(f"{link}\n")
```